# Need help transferring from Electron Remote to IPC for remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow() remote.getCurrentWindow() and remote.dialog

Tags: electron, ipc

Electron remote is being deprecated as of version 14, and I would like to transfer over to using IPC main and IPC renderer. I am newer to coding and working on a personal project so a full explanation is greatly appreciated. I am unable to find any instructionals on how to accomplish the following using IPC, and not much fully explaining how to practically use IPC main and IPC renderer period. The tasks at hand involves using puppeteer to print a pdf and customized titlebar controls.

```
const remote = require('electron').remote
const focusedWindow = remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()
const dialog = remote.dialog,
const currentWindow = remote.getCurrentWindow()
```

Comment: HI @jomortal, have you looked at the other answers on SO and what about them didn't help? e.g. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015044/electron-printtopdf-from-browserwindow>

Comment: @MrR Thank you, that's a much clearer example than I've been finding. Also, nice if I don't need to use puppeteer. I'll see if I can't get it to work.